# Will attacking with a magical or wonderous item overcome damage reduction?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, damage

As I recall, magical weapons can overcome damage reduction. If one were to attack an enemy with a wonderous item, like say attacking with an everfull mug in a barfight would it overcome an enemies damage reduction?

Comment: You mean an improvised attack with a magic object that isn't specifically a weapon? If you're the DM, I might just "forget" about the NPC's DR for the good of the game.

Comment: Yes, a magic object that isn't specifically a weapon. One of my future characters I'm planning on is a cannibalistic half orc bard, who cooks his own food with a magic frying pan... that he also plans on attacking with as a secondary weapon, and was wondering how it would apply to damage reduction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No**, wondrous items such as an Everfull Mug or Piero's Pan of Flameless Frying wouldn't overcome damage resistance (magic) if they were used as improvised weapons.

Damage Reduction<sup>[SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#damageReduction)</sup> is only overcome by magic weapons when the DR is *specifically* vulnerable to magic weapons and when the weapon in question has at least a +1 magical enhancement bonus<sup>[SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#enhancementBonus)</sup>. Otherwise, magic weapons' damage is reduced just like any other weapon.

The only exception is if the weapon *just happens* to satisfy the conditions of the damage reduction some other way, of course; e.g., a silver Everfull Mug that doesn't have a magical weapon bonus would overcome damage reduction (silver) just fine, though not because it was magical.

The interaction of damage reduction and magic weapons is a frequent point of confusion in D&D 3.x, possibly since in the edition prior a creature immune to damage but vulnerable to particular material (like silver) was *also* automatically vulnerable to any magic weapon. When damage reduction was introduced in D&D 3.0 to fill the same rules function but without producing the same results, that it worked contrary to expectations caused problems for my group and others I knew. Then again, the frequent confusion might have nothing to do with edition changes – the DR rules are generally recognised as one of the more confusingly-written parts of the rules.

Despite the rules saying "no", your GM's game is your GM's game – they can tweak the rules as they see fit!

Comment: It's worth noting that upgrading a wondrous item to overcome magic damage reduction would cost only 3,000 gp: 2,000 gp to enchant it as a +1 weapon, and +50% for adding a second different ability to the same item.